# Retrieving a JSON array from PHP script using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Yesterday I wrote my first code using jQuery to pass variables from Javascript to a PHP script using `$.ajax`, so I'm definitely not an expert.

Today I was trying to pass an array as a result of a PHP query to the HTML file; they suggested me to use JSON so I collected all the information and I tried to write a code that, obviously, doesn't work.

The aim is to pass this array and access (via jQuery) to the values separately and print them in separately in different part of the HTML page. The problem is that the AJAX call returns `error:` (displaying in console: "Failed").

Can anyone help me to understand which is the problem?

the HTML file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuSelect").on("click", function(){
        var str = $("#menuSelect").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tester2.php",
            data: { value: str },
            dataType:"Json",
            success: function(data){
                var a = $.parseJSON(data);
                $("#txt").html(a.name);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP file

```
function provaAJAX($value) {
switch ($value) {
    case "0":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=1", "", "", "Error");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($query);
        break;
    case "1":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=2", "", "", "Error");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($query);
        break;
    case "2":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=3", "", "", "Error");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($query);
        break;
}
}

$value = $_POST["value"];
provaAJAX($value);
```

Comment: What else is there in a console?

Comment: @u_mulder Nothing else, unfortunately. Just written Failed and the correspondent line of `console.log("Failed")` in the HTML file

Comment: There should be some data about your request to `tester2.php` Check carefully.

Comment: If it is chrome - check `Network` tab in a console.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't know if maybe I could find some other information elsewhere, but into the console I just have Failed. Maybe I'm missing something, but the page is here [link](http://99poses.it/test/ajaxarray.html)

Comment: Ok, this is really strange. Are you sure that your `http://99poses.it/test/tester2.php` works as expected?

Comment: Do some debugging for this file. Maybe some errors happen during it's execution but we don;t see them?

Comment: @u_mulder Yep, I've tested it pushing into the `provaAJAX($value)` a `$value` = 0 and it prints out this string that, as far as I learned today, should be the correct form of an array transformed into a JSON string `[{"name":"carbonio","lvl":"0"}]`. I think the problem is into the HTML file, but I just started with jQuery, AJAX & JSON. so I don't really know what it could be

Comment: I see empty response from tester2 file. Are you sure that it really works as you expect? Try to echo something there.

Comment: @u_mulder I hoped `json` extension was disabled on the server but I just checked and it enabled. To be honest I don't know how I could echo something from `tester2.php` since it's called by AJAX (which fails) and not directly. I think I didn't understand; can you explain me? Really thanks for the help you're giving me!

Comment: @u_mulder I create a HTML temp file that directly links to `tester2.php` passing to it the same exactly values (0 or 1) as the other HTML page with AJAX does; it seems it works [link](http://99poses.it/test/tempstack.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that PHP was designed to handle url encoded form data, not JSON. So, if you plan to pass JSON data to a PHP script, you cannot use `$_POST` since that is simply a decoding of url encoded form data, you have to do something like

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = json_decode($data, true);
```

At that point, you can access $_POST the way you are used to.